# basic rails question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
  class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_uniqueness_of :user_name, :scope => :account_id
  end
```

my question is about the above three lines of code. by the way I'm c++ programmer and new to ruby and rails. I'm very very confused by the line: `validates_...` what's that? variable
definition? function call? or something eles. For me, it's a weird line whithin a class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a function call.

The function is defined in module (ActiveRecord::Validations). Modules in Ruby are objects and can have functions and variables attached to them.

You can include module and get it's members. Here it's done in your parent class: ActiveRecord::Base. If You look at it's definition it starts with something like:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    include ActiveRecord::Naming
    # ...
    include ActiveRecord::Validations
    #...
  end
end
```

There are some noticeable differences in way C++ and Ruby handles class declaration. Firstly, there is no compilation in Ruby. So class definition can be changed during runtime. And actually it's the default way of declaring a class. In other words: classes in Ruby are always open.

Secondly, class body can have any executable code. In C++ you can't invoke a function from class definition. It wouldn't make much sense. Yet in Ruby it makes, since You are able to do metaprogramming. This way you can invoke a function which constructs some members. That's writing functions which can write another functions. It can be a big productivity boost and a source of worst errors at the same time.

I'd highly recommend consulting the [Ruby Metaprogramming: Declaratively Adding Methods to a Class](http://www.vitarara.org/cms/ruby_metaprogamming_declaratively_adding_methods_to_a_class) entry.

Comment: @demas, rekin and anukul: how could a function call occurs in the definition of a class in ruby? which part of ruby I should if I want to fully understand this

Comment: @Haiyuan, I added two paragraphs to elaborate on that. Basically Rails is very mature framework using a lot of metaprogramming. Behind the scenes ActiveRecord objects are empowered with tens of fields and functions to handle (among others) validation, typecasting, SQL translation.

Answer (score 2):

It's a function call. You could rewrite it as `validates_uniqueness_off(:user_name, :scope => :account_id)`. In Ruby, the convention is to ignore these parentheses. Rails gives you these class methods as part of `ActiveRecord::Validations` module. The [rails API](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000086) can give you more information about how it's defined and you can also take look at the sources to see how it's implemented. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is a function call. You can find [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) more examples of validations of model.